# How do i show Google maps in Windows Phone 8.1 Javascript app

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-maps-api-3, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying a small app of showing some markers on a google map in a Windows 8.1 mobile app. Here is my requirement :
1. Get the user current location
2. Pass the current location of user (CoOrdinates) to a Web api and get some more coodinates nearby (Now you will have some coordinates).
3. Display google map of that region and show these markers. The markers may be change from default to pushpins (UI change)
4. On click of any marker it shows a popup with some imfo.

I have been trying to get a sample working but failing.

I have tried this as below. Initialy I just truied to get current location and show it in google map.

Created a WP 8.1 navigation app and added a pushpin page code as below (Default.html navigates to to pushpin.html)

Code :

Pushpin.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>H2Observer</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <!-- At runtime, ui-themed.css resolves to ui-themed.light.css or ui-themed.dark.css 
    based on the user’s theme setting. This is part of the MRT resource loading functionality. -->
    <link href="/css/ui-themed.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- H2Observer references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/navigator.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="phone">
    <div id="contenthost" data-win-control="Application.PageControlNavigator" data-win-options="{home: '/pages/pushpin/pushpin.html'}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Pushpin.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    //var geolocator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
    //var getGeopositionPromise;
    var disposed;

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/pushpin/pushpin.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            getGeopositionPromise = geolocator.getGeopositionAsync();
            var that = this;
            getGeopositionPromise.done(
            function (pos) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    that.displayPosition(pos);
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    that.displayError(pos);
                }
            }

            );


        },

        displayPosition: function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coordinate.latitude, position.coordinate.longitude);
            var options = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: pos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.body.getElementById("map"), options);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: "User location"
            });
            var contentString = "<b>Timestamp:</b> " + this.parseTimestamp(position.timestamp) + "<br/><b>User location:</b> lat " + position.coords.latitude + ", long " + position.coords.longitude + ", accuracy " + position.coords.accuracy;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        },

        displayError: function (error) {
            var errors = {
                1: 'Permission denied',
                2: 'Position unavailable',
                3: 'Request timeout'
            };
            alert("Error: " + errors[error.code] + error.message);
        },

        parseTimestamp: function (timestamp) {
            var d = new Date(timestamp);
            var day = d.getDate();
            var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            var hour = d.getHours();
            var mins = d.getMinutes();
            var secs = d.getSeconds();
            var msec = d.getMilliseconds();
            return day + "." + month + "." + year + " " + hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + "," + msec;
        }


    });
})();
```

If I run the above code it throws me "google is undefined".

I did a search and somewhere it said to encapsulate the page in Iframe. I wrapped this pushpin page in an Iframe (by implementating another page with IFrame with source to this page ). In Pushpin.js I removed all code and just kept below :

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.body.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -187.3),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            });
```

But it just shows blank screen in app.

I am not getting any help on this. I would like to know your thoughts around this and if what I am trying to achieve is possible/feasible. Would also love some pointers also.

Waiting for an response.

Thanks
- Girija

Comment: I can't  see where  you load the maps-API inside your code

Comment: I am doing that in displyPosition function :     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.body.getElementById("map"), options);

Comment: [**how to load the maps-API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Comment: Sorry but still doesnot work. I am now doubting wether it is supported in the first place or not. can someone please confirm this.

Comment: using bing maps would be a better option.I have previously tried using google maps was struck into similar issues.